# Determine parameters of a gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

I have x values and y values (see below)

x: 76.6, 52.5, 3.5, 15, 71.5, 161.83333, 154, 72.5,
39
40
23
14.5
5.5
78
129
73.5
100
10
3
29.5
65
44
68.5
56.5
52.14286
66.5
106
36.6
10
135
46.5

y: 110.50969
391.49284
-519.81424
-15.63718
139.70321
39.03956
-40.27464
19.84898
-121.40739
-94.93083
-57.90076
-148.11688
-220.61315
157.12958
61.05487
46.83268
30.80436
-25.48031
-108.25846
95.62236
67.76833
82.148
76.88637
224.2562
444.81261
308.19817
181.89635
59.17169
-95.20256
255.49925
368.34707

I want to fit the data to a gamma function: A*(x^B)*(exp(k*x)). 
However I cannot find a way to find the parameters value A, B and k. Does someone know how I can solve this equation according to my data?

Comment: I guess you mean gamma **distribution**? See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Parameter_estimation. Your function is definitely **no** gamma function.

Comment: Thanks. Why it cannot be a gamma function? It is supposed to be a gamma family function